# Access Database Form ActiveX control error

Tags: ms-access, activex, vba

I'm using a form that has date picker controls on it.  When the form is opened and the datepicker control (MSCOMCT2.OCX) is clicked, I get the following unhelpful error:

> The expression Change you entered as the even property setting
>   produced the following error: There was an error loading an ActiveX
>   control on one of your forms or reports.
>
> *The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure.]
>   *There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

I can dismiss this message, but then get the same thing complaining about

> MouseMove

I haven't specified these events in the vba, so I'm at a loss for what could be causing this.

The problem Does not happen when I run it on my winXP w/ Access 2007 PC or my winXP w/ Access 2003 PC, but does happen on all other tested winXP w/ Access 2003's.  Registering MSCOMCT2.OCX has no effect.

What could be causing this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint so that you can step through the code. That way you will see the line that causes the error.

Comment: @cularis - I'd like to, but I don't even have those events declared in my vba.  WHere would I set the breakpoint?

Comment: Don't know your code, maybe you can paste it here or to pastebin or someting. I would try setting it somewhere where the control is being called in the code.

Comment: Another thing I just thought of: you may have not have the routine in code, but maybe you have set them on the properties window for the control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My impression is most experienced Access developers avoid ActiveX controls whenever possible.  For a date picker, you definitely don't need ActiveX.

See [Popup Calendar](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-51.html) by Allen Browne.  I've used his form (the version for "Access 2000 and later") successfully with both Access 2003 and 2007.

If that one is not to your liking, visit the links he provided (at the bottom of that page) for other approaches.

Comment: To add to HansUp reply.  We avoid ActiveX controls because of the distribution, version and killbit problems.   Distribution problems mean, for example, if the user already has Access, runtime or retail, installed any ActiveX controls require admins to do the install.  Without them we can just give the users the front end Access database file.   Version problems are about when the user has a different version than you do for whatever reason.  Also if you update their version then another app installed on that machine could break and you'd be blamed.

Comment: Killbit problems means that when MS find a security flaw in an ActiveX control the next MS Update then "cancels" that particular ActiveX control.  With basically no warning to you.  And you are left trying to figure out the problem  which can be very difficult to trouble shoot if you've never heard of the basic causes.

Comment: To be honest I'm not even sure we can conclusively pin the problem on this control (although I think the problem is there).  How can I "confirm" that this control is the issue?  I don't want to replace unless I have to, it works great (when it works).

Comment: I don't understand why you have any doubts.  Does your form include **other** ActiveX controls ... which could trigger the error "*There was an error loading an ActiveX control*" ?

Comment: Make a copy of the form.  Delete the ActiveX control from that copy.  Does the error go away with that copy of the form?

Comment: @HansUp -Your right, that was a stupid question.  I confirmed it, its the datepickers.  Seems like everyone wants me to replace it?  I'll explore those options.

Comment: @HansUp -This did fix the situation, although I should point out that we still didn't fix the actual problem.  But it works, so lets move on!  :-)

Comment: My tongue-in-cheek response: The actual problem was using an ActiveX control on your form.  You're not now.  Therefore, problem solved.  :-)