# Embedding a Layered PDF into an Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, adobe, activex, acrobat

I am constructing a Microsoft Access 2016 (32-bit) database that shows information about roads, and I want to have a control on a form that allows the user to interact with a pdf through Adobe Acrobat. I have tried inserting an ActiveX control, but the first error that throws after inserting some code to display the .pdf file is "Error: The OLE server isn't registered. To register the OLE server, reinstall it." After that, "run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" pops up and highlights

My code currently:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\Users\username1\Documents\CountyMapFile1.pdf"
AcroPDF0.src = filePath
AcroPDF0.setShowToolbar (False)
AcroPDF0.setShowScrollbars (False)
AcroPDF0.setLayoutMode ("SinglePage")
AcroPDF0.setPageMode ("none")
AcroPDF0.setView ("Fit")
AcroPDF0.Height = 9000
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShowToolbar_Click()
If cmdShowToolbar Then
AcroPDF0.setShowToolbar (True)
Me.cmdShowToolbar.Caption = "Hide ToolBar"
Else
AcroPDF0.setShowToolbar (False)
Me.cmdShowToolbar.Caption = "Show ToolBar"
End If
End Sub
```

I want to use the Acrobat Reader specifically because the .pdf in question is a map that has layers used to explore features contained within the map. [Here are links to the maps in question](https://connect.ncdot.gov/resources/State-Mapping/Pages/County-Bridge-Maps.aspx). Select a county and then select County Maps, then you can download the Layered .pdf files from there. To use the layer capabilities, one must use the model tree in order to be able to select specific features. The model tree isn't accessible when opening the file in an internet browser, so a Web browser control on the form is not an option unfortunately.

I have scoured the internet looking for the solution, but either my knowledge is too limited to understand what I need to do or I simply can't find it.

[This conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682322/access-database-form-activex-control-error) says to not even use ActiveX controls. But I have no idea what my other options are (besides third-party, costly solutions.)

So my question is how do I register the OLE server and continue with developing this solution?

My PC is running Windows 10 64-Bit. I hope that this is an issue that can be resolved to where I won't have to replicate the solution on every machine that will eventually be using this database as it's put onto the shared drive on the network.

Comment: It's my understanding that Adobe/PDF manipulation requires install of Acrobat, not just the Reader.

Comment: I can't pull it up on my home computer right now since it doesn't have Acrobat, but there's an option for Acrobat DC Browser Implementation or something similar, but I assumed that was using an internet browser window

Comment: Taking a closer look at your code. Nowhere do you show declaring and setting Adobe objects. Here is example of code manipulating Adobe objects http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=25574

Comment: Okay, been exploring this. Since posted code is intended to work with ActiveX control, it is very different from the Adobe object code I referenced in previous comment. I have never had success with ActiveX controls and installing dll's; and, yes, everything I've read advised to avoid ActiveX. I tried to adapt my code but the intrinsic Adobe library doesn't seem to have the methods and elements referenced in the ActiveX code. Documentation for any Adobe interaction/automation is scarce. Sorry, I got nothing.

Comment: The exact verbiage of the ActiveX control that I was referring to is "Adobe Acrobat DC Browser Control Implementation", so I was really close off the top of my head. But that is discouraging to hear; I'll keep trying though. I will work with the link you have given me and go from there.

Comment: This isn't an answer to this question, but I wanted to share what I ended up doing to accomplish this task; I used a Web Browser control on the Microsoft form and I have programmed it to where users select the pdf based on selection from a combobox on the same form. The process is detailed here ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeyoRBTAa9I)), but my product is quite different from this seeing as I won't have my users picking the file that they open. So no ActiveX control, but this works just fine.

Comment: I thought this would not allow PDF layers to function so would not be satisfactory?

Comment: I had assumed that since it's a web browser control that it would only open links in a web browser window. But, if you put the link as a file location, then whatever your default program is set to is what will be used. The only downside of this is ensuring everyone has their default PDF viewer as Acrobat